# 'Brief description' synonyms

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to think of synonyms for two similar descriptions but where the length of the actual description is different. I have checked [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32739/synonym-for-description) thread, but I want feedback due to the nature of the lengths in question.

The first is a word for a very short description of something, like a single sentence in length.

> Highland events in the south-east promote tourism.

I was thinking tagline, but tagline seems to be associated with marketing or advertising.

The second is a word for a more detailed and lengthy description of something, more like a paragraph in length.

> The Highlands’ events also include some of Scotland’s most popular music festivals including Belladrum Tartan Heart Festival and RockNess. The legendary Spirit of Speyside Whisky Festival always promises to be a memorable weekend, with lots of tastings, demonstrations and live music.

I was thinking excerpt, but this seems to apply to media in being a direct quotation rather than a description.

Comment: Synopsis, summary, summarization, précis, abstract, outline, digest, rundown, roundup, abridgment.

Comment: "tl;dr" (long) and "tl;drtldr" (short) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (short) *blurb* is a "comment".
The longer *blurb* is a "description".

If you were asking someone to write these, for example, to accompany a photo, you could request a "short blurb", (usually a single sentence) or a "long blurb" (a short paragraph). (US)

Ex: Let's include a *blurb* about the Highland Events in this article.